# Which headers for file upload in Perl?

Tags: perl, file, upload, header

I've been stuck on this for quite a couple of hours and I haven't been able to find a solution for it by researching.

The following HTML code will work for what I require:

```
<form action="uploader.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="Filedata" id="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

However, the following Perl code does not work. I assume this is because I'm not sending the headers required.

```
my @headers  = ('Content-Disposition' => 'form-data; name="Filedata"; filename="test.txt"',
                'Content-Type'        => 'text/plain',
                'Content'             => 'File content goes here.');

my $browser  = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $browser->post('uploader.php', undef, @headers);
```

If anyone can point out the reason it doesn't work I would be grateful.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried adapting the example of POST with form data from http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Message-6.06/lib/HTTP/Request/Common.pm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my $response = $ua->post('http://.../uploader.php',
   Content_Type => 'form-data',
   Content => [
      Filedata => [ undef, 'test.txt',
         Content_Type => 'text/plain',
         Content      => "Hello, World!\n",
      ],
      submit => 'Submit',
   ],
);
```

The args for `->post` are the same args for [HTTP::Request::Common](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP%3a%3aRequest%3a%3aCommon)'s `POST` sub.

It's also capable of reading the file from disk for you if that's what you actually want to do.

```
my $response = $ua->post('http://.../uploader.php',
   Content_Type => 'form-data',
   Content => [
      Filedata => [ 'test.txt', 'test.txt',
         Content_Type => 'text/plain',
      ],
      submit => 'Submit',
   ],
);
```

Comment: Looks like @hobbs posted nearly the same thing as me while I was composing my answer. Differences: 1) I didn't forget the form's second field (`submit`, though the script will probably ignore it anyway), 2) I didn't forget to specify the content type of the file in one of the two snippets (though LWP will try to guess a default), and 3) my syntax is not only shorter, it doesn't require you to use `use HTTP::Request::Common qw( POST );`.

Comment: Even better!
No need for the extra module then.
Thanks a lot man!

Comment: The module is still being used; you just don't need to deal with it yourself.

Answer (score 7):

You're providing a Content-Type of `text/plain`, which is obviously wrong — you need to be sending a `multipart/form-data` MIME message with the file as a `text/plain` enclosure. You *could* do this by hand with a MIME module, but as jpalecek points out, [HTTP::Request::Common](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Request::Common) already knows how to do it for you. A request like this should work:

```
my $response = $browser->request(
    POST "http://somewhere/uploader.php",
        Content_Type => 'form-data',
        Content => [
            Filedata => [ 
                undef,
                "test.txt",
                Content_Type => "text/plain",
                Content => "file content goes here"
            ]
        ]
);
```

Or if test.txt actually exists on disk:

```
my $response = $browser->request(
    POST "http://somewhere/uploader.php",
        Content_Type => 'form-data',
        Content => [
            Filedata => [ "/path/to/test.txt" ]
        ]
);
```

will be enough. In either case, just make sure to add `use HTTP::Request::Common;` to your code.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly.
I did try with setting the `Content-Type` header to `form-data`, alas it failed.
Thanks to you I see why though, I understand. Thanks again.