# add additional parameters to Perl upload

Tags: perl, file-upload, box

While trying to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13329157/2002471) on uploading use Perl's LWP to [box](/questions/tagged/box)'s API I ran into a problem.  Box expects to receive a `parent` parameter [to upload a file](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#upload-a-file) which I cannot convince Perl to pass along.

```
# setup LWP
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->default_header( 'Authorization' => "Bearer $devkey" );

# upload files
my @files = qw(day.jpg morning.jpg night.jpg);                                                                                  
foreach my $file (@files) {                                                                                                     
        my $fqfn = $file;                                                                                                       
        $fqfn =~ s{^}{/usr/share/backgrounds/};                                                                                 
        print "$file $fqfn\n";                                                                                                  
        die "no file $file" unless -f $fqfn;                                                                                    

        my $resp = $ua->post( "https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content",                                                   
                Content_Type => 'form-data',                                                                                    
                Content => [                                                                                                    
                        Filedata => [ $fqfn, $file,                                                                             
                                Content_Type => 'image/jpg',                                                                    
                                parent => $customer_dir_id,                                                                     
                        ],                                                                                                      
                ],                                                                                                              
        );                                                                                                                      
        unless ($resp->is_success) {                                                                                            
                print Dumper($resp);                                                                                            
                print "ERROR: upload $file failed\n\n";                                                                         
                print "returned " . $resp->code() . "\n";                                                                       
                my $box_resp = $json_parser->decode( $resp->decoded_content );                                                  
                print Dumper($box_resp);                                                                                        
                die "see above";                                                                                                
        }                                                                                                                       

        die "devel";                                                                                                            
}
```

I keep getting back:

```
{
      'status' => 400,
      'request_id' => 'bfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbfb',
      'type' => 'error',
      'context_info' => {
                 'errors' => [
                               {
                                 'name' => 'parent',
                                 'reason' => 'missing_parameter',
                                 'message' => '\'parent\' is required'
                               }
                             ]
                        },
      'message' => 'Bad Request',
      'help_url' => 'http://developers.box.com/docs/#errors',
      'code' => 'bad_request'
 };
```

Notes:

- I'm using the 1 hour dev key.
- I haven't had any trouble with other method's in the API.  I can traverse folder and make folders just fine.

So, basically, how can I add in the `parent` parameter to a file upload?

## update

Here is the code for structuring the request properly:

```
    my $req = POST "https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content",                                                             
            Content_Type => 'form-data',                                                                                       
            Content => [                                                                                                       
                    attributes => '{"name":"'. $file .'", "parent":{"id":"'. $customer_dir_id .'"}}',                          
                    file => [ $fqfn ],                                                                                         
            ],                                                                                                                 
    ;                                                                                                                          

    my $resp = $ua->request($req);
```

Comment: Does the parameter (`parent`) belong outside `Filedata`, like [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13329178)?

Comment: @mob I tried that, but the fact that parent wasn't structured as an "object" with an `id` field inside of squiggly brackets `{}` seems to be the main problem.

Comment: In this case, building the `attributes` JSON by hand is simple enough that it's probably not a big deal, but in general I would use the JSON module.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot You are absolutely correct.  This is a bit hackish, but I'm glad Perl can do it™.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the example `curl` command in the [box documentation](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#upload-a-file):

```
curl https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" -X POST \
  -F attributes='{"name":"tigers.jpeg", "parent":{"id":"11446498"}}' \
  -F file=@myfile.jpg
```

This generates a request where:

- the `Authorization` header has the value `Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN`
- the `attributes` form field has the value `{"name":"tigers.jpeg", "parent":{"id":"11446498"}}`
- the `file` form field gets the content from the file `myfile.jpg`

Since LWP::UserAgent's `post` method is just a wrapper for `HTTP::Request::Common::POST`, it's easy to create a request object and check that it's generating what you want:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTTP::Request::Common;

my $request = POST 'https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content',
    Authorization => 'Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN',
    Content_Type  => 'form-data',
    Content       => [ attributes => '{"name":"tigers.jpeg", "parent":{"id":"11446498"}}',
                       file       => [ 'foo' ] ];

print $request->as_string;
```

Outputs:

```
POST https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
Content-Length: 237
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=xYzZY

--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attributes"

{"name":"tigers.jpeg", "parent":{"id":"11446498"}}
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="foo"
Content-Type: text/plain

foo
bar
baz

--xYzZY--
```

Comment: I had the `Authorization` header fixed outside of the code I initially pasted in.  I added that part in now to make it clearer.